# How can I use the firebase-admin 'generateEmailVerificationLink' function in firebase cloud-functions beforeCreate()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to build an app that authenticate through firebase. During the whole process I found that firebase release in any case a token even if email is not verified.

Because I want firebase give me a token only when email is verified I decided to use firebase-cloud-functions to check through the `beforeCreate()` function if a user's email was enabled and if not, send an email for verification generating an email link using 'firebase-admin' `admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink`.

According cloud-functions documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#common-scenarios it is possible to configure firebase-admin in cloud function in this way:

```
 exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  const locale = context.locale;
  if (user.email && !user.emailVerified) {
    // Send custom email verification on sign-up.
    return admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(user.email).then((link) => {
      return sendCustomVerificationEmail(user.email, link, locale);
    });
  }
});
```

Apparently this doesn't work!!! In my case when I create a user I receive following error code:

```
FirebaseAuthError: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.
```

Doing some other research it seems that to generate the email verification link FirebaseAuth should have already create or authenticate the user.

How is this thing not working since it's in the documentation? Do you have an idea about how this really work? Any example or detail would be great!!!

Thank to all.

Comment: Are you using Firebase Admin 11.5.0? If so, based on the documentation from Identity Toolkit, the [`sendOobCode` endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-send-email-verification) used by `generateEmailVerificationLink()` expects an ID token for the user given by the email - but as the user doesn't exist yet, the ID token can't be generated. You should report this as a bug directly to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) so they can flag it with GC Identity Toolkit team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using the 11.2.0 but now I've update the library to the 11.5.  Yes! I write to Firebase Support and see what they say.

Comment: Why would you do this through Firebase admin? You can include email verification as a must-have during registration process if you use [`firebase/auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).

Comment: @LucaT You can use [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) instead of `beforeCreate` .[beforeCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#understanding_blocking_functions) is called before the user record is actually created in Firebase Auth. so there is no user

Comment: @JoeMoore I don't like the way flow Is working...i know that you can send email verification with firebase/auth bit in any case you receive the token even of email Is not verified..and that Is not correct from my point of view. Also on my project i have a backend service doing other stuff that check token validity and so on.. I wrote the support and as i was saying documentation Is not correct.